# My gcc compiler gives me an, error that shows as Conflicting types for (function)

Tags: c, compilation, compiler-errors

I'm new to C and i made this program and i'm getting an error 
"conflicting types for (function)"
"previous declaration of (function) was here".

I compiled this using gcc compiler of Dev c++ using command prompt on my system.
Can anyone help me understand my fault here ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
main()
{
    int a,b,c;
    float area;
    float ar(int a,int b,int c);
    printf("Enter the lenghts of the three sides of a triangle");
    scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c);
    area=ar(a,b,c);
    printf("The are a of the triangle is=%.2f",area);
}
ar(a,b,c)
{
    float area,s;
    s=(a+b+c)/3;
    area=sqrt((s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)));
    return area;
}
```

Comment: Have you gone through a basic C book or tutorial?

Comment: Does it literally say "conflicting types for (function)"????  Or are you concealing the function name from us for some reason.

Comment: it says 
conflicting types for 'ar'
previous declaration of 'ar' was here

Comment: I suspect it's complaining about `ar(a,b,c)` which lacks a return specification.

Comment: Well you better look for better learning material. `ar(a,b,c)` that is a very bad way to declare a function. Instead, declare it with full typing: `float ar(int a, int b, int c) { ...}`. By not declaring a return type, the compiler assumes it is `int`. Which conflicts with the declaration of the function inside `main` (which is also not good practice).

Comment: ok that helped but @DavidHoelzer it still me the area of triangle as 0, can you suggest a fix please ?

Comment: That wasn't in your original question.  The problem is that you are using ints.

Comment: thanks @kaylum, this worked but when i enter sides of a triangle, the compiler program returns 0.

Comment: and what can i use instead of that ? @DavidHoelzer

Comment: I amended the answer.

Comment: @LoganAnderson : I have added an answer with a bit more explanation. I see that you're using `Heron's` formula to calculate the area. The semiperimeter is calculated by dividing the sums of sides by 2 not 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you specify a return type in your prototype but not in the actual function definition.  When you write the prototype with a particular definition you must follow that same definition when writing the actual function.

I've also cast the integer addition into a float so that you can properly calculate the area. When you take an integer and divide it by a float in C you will end up with an integer regardless of what you are assigning it into. The cast will change this behavior.

Consider this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    int a,b,c;
    float area;
    float ar(int a,int b,int c);
    printf("Enter the lenghts of the three sides of a triangle");
    scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c);
    area=ar(a,b,c);
    printf("The are a of the triangle is=%.2f",area);
}
float ar(int a,int b,int c)
{
    float area,s;
    s=(float)(a+b+c)/3;
    area=sqrt((s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)));
    return area;
}
```

This will compile cleanly.

Comment: Great, got it now, will always remember, can't thank enough, i think this might've been an error in of my previous programs thanks.

Comment: An up vote and acceptance is all the thanks I need. ;)

Comment: Although this compiles, it's poor style. The parameters should be declared as `int a, int b, int c`. Also, since the prototype is inside `main` the compiler is actually not required to diagnose the bug if the definition doesn't match (e.g. the case in the original code). It would be much better to have the prototype before `main`.

Answer (score 2):

You declared your function "ar" with return type float but float ar(int a,int b,int c); but you defined it with no return value.That rised a problem here.
try this:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<math.h>
    float ar(int a,int b,int c);

    void main()
    {
        int a,b,c;
        float area;
        printf("Enter the lenghts of the three sides of a triangle");
        scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c);
        area=ar(a,b,c);
        printf("The are a of the triangle is=%.2f",area);
    }
    float ar(int a,int b,int c)
    {
        float area,s;
        s=(a+b+c)/3;
        area=sqrt((s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)));
       return area;
   }
```

Compile with the command :gcc -std=c99 -o stack_16_4_16 stack_16_4_16.c -lm

Answer (score 0):

I tried to include a bit of explanation here :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

float ar(int a,int b,int c); 
/*  This is a function declaration and just like variables, functions are
 *  also limited by scope. If you declare the function inside the main,
 *  then the function cannot be called outside the main. That is the purpose
 *  it is declared here.
 */

int main()
{
    int a,b,c;
    float area;

    printf("Enter the lengths of the three sides of a triangle : ");
    scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c);
    area=ar(a,b,c);
    printf("The are a of the triangle is = %.2f",area);

    return 0;
}

    float ar(int a,int b,int c)  
    /* Note that I have added the types of arguments
     * In older versions of C it is not uncommon to see functions like 
     * float ar(a,b)
     * int a,b;
     * {Some Stuff Here}
     * The above function style was problematic - it couldn't deal with mismatched arguments.
     * So it is a good practice to specify the type of the parameters.
     * In fact this was ANSI C standard's solution to the problems of mismatched arguments.
     */
    {
    float area,s;
    s=(a+b+c)/(float)2;  
    /* Either the numerator or the denominator  should be float for the output to be float
     * So I casted the denominator to a float value. Also, if you're using Heron's formula
     * the denominator should be 2 , not 3.
     */

    area=sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c));

    return area;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a return type to your function ar

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
main()
{
    int a,b,c;
    float area;
    float ar(int a,int b,int c);
    printf("Enter the lenghts of the three sides of a triangle");
    scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c);
    area=ar(a,b,c);
    printf("The are a of the triangle is=%.2f",area);
}
float ar(float a, float b, float c)
{
    float area,s;
    s=(a+b+c)/3;
    area=sqrt((s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)));
    return area;
}
```